# How to retrieve a value from json with $resource in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How I can retrieve a value from a call with $resoure and use it in JS, no only in my views with data binding?

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "id": 18,
    "name": "adsfadsf",
    "type_of_dish": "Tacos",
    "cost": "5.95",
    "notes": "bla bla bla",
    "totalrecipes": 1,
    "dish_recipes_attributes": [
        {
            "recipe_id": 28,
            "no_recipe": 1,
            "name": "tacos al pastor piña",
            "cost_portion": "5.95"
        }
    ]
}
```

in my JS:

```
$scope.dish = Dish.get({id: $routeParams.id});
```

I need to get the value "totalrecipes", I've tried with this without successfull:

```
var totalrecipes = $scope.dish.totalrecipes;
console.log(totalrecipes);  //Undefined
console.log($scope.dish); // [object Object]
```

But in my view everything is ok:

```
{{dish.totalrecipes}}   // 1, It's OK!
```

Answer (score 5):

Remember that the action functions of a resource are *asynchronous* and return only a *promise* object. You can read up on that in the [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) and [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) documentations. The view is actually designed to update itself once a promise is "fulfilled", that's why the value is displayed in your view.

Consider the following example:

```
$scope.dish = Dish.get({id: 123})
alert($scope.dish.totalrecipes);
```

In this case, `$scope.dish` will be assigned a promise object until the actual value is loaded (which may happen at any point later in time, or not at all).

Instead, you can use a callback method, either directly as argument of the `get`function, or using the *promise* API:

```
$scope.dish = Dish.get({id: 123}, function(dish) {
    alert(dish.totalrecipes);
});
```

Alternatively:

```
$scope.dish = Dish.get({id: 123})
$scope.dish.$promise.then(function(dish) {
    alert(dish.totalrecipes);
});
```

Comment: @IsraelBarba, please also consider accepting this answer if it fully answered your question. ;)